# How to exit from gnu grub menu and start linux normally

Tags: grub2, gnu

Kindly consider this, have tried tried exit on grub terminal its not working

Comment: My os is linux 18.04 and grub menu opened up (may b some keys got pressed while starting system) just want to exit from here and start my sytem normally

Comment: Yes waiting on screen (gnu grub main menu) have entered c and in grub command line entered exit, normal_exit but still on main menu screen how to exit from here? Yes press f2 now what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in the kernel selection menu, i.e. something that looks like this:

[image: Kernel selection menu]

then use the up arrow key until the topmost (= most recent) kernel is highlighted and press ENTER to boot into that kernel.

If, on the other hand, you accidentally pressed 'e' while in that menu and opened up the kernel command line:

[image: Kernel command line]

then press Ctrl-X to proceed.

Comment: Gnu grub has following options *ubuntu advance ubuntu settings, memory test , memory test how to exit from here and start system normally

Comment: @MaleehaKhan As in this: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/grub2-in-ubuntu.jpg ? If so, then use the up arrow key until "Ubuntu" is highlighted and press Enter to boot into the default kernel.

Comment: Have tried it selected ubuntu and initramfs start

Comment: @MaleehaKhan Nice, sounds like your issue was resolved. If so, would you mind marking this as the accepted answer?